# Nextflow sarek pipeline on AWS batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, nextflow

How to run nextflow sarek pipeline using aws batch in cloud9 environment?

I tried and I am getting "

```
  Essential container in task exited
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to run jobs using [AWS Batch](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/aws.html#aws-batch), Nextflow requires access to the AWS CLI (i.e. `aws`) from within each of the containers that the pipeline has specified. To do this, you will need to create a [custom AMI](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/aws.html#custom-ami) and use Conda (or another package manager) to install the AWS CLI tool. Ensure that your AMI also has Docker installed, see: [docker installation](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/aws.html#docker-installation).

> The reason is that when the AWS CLI tool executes using Conda it will
> use the version of python supplied by Conda. If you don’t use Conda
> and install the AWS CLI using something like [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) the `aws` command will
> attempt to run using the version of python found in the running
> container which won’t be able to find the necessary dependencies.

In your [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) settings, create an *ecsInstanceRole* and attach the `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` policies. Then, when configuring a [Compute Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environments.html) for AWS Batch, you will need to specify this instance role in step 1. Make sure to also supply the custom AMI ID (created above) when configuring the instance (under *additional configuration*) in step 2. You can then create a [Job Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_queues.html) and attach the compute environment to it. Finally, create an [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket to write the results to.

---

Then get started with [Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/) by creating and opening up an environment. The first job is to install Nextflow and move it to somewhere in your $PATH:

```
$ curl -s https://get.nextflow.io | bash
$ mkdir ~/bin && mv nextflow ~/bin
```

Then, with the following in `~/.nextflow/config` for example:

```
plugins {
    id 'nf-amazon'
}

process {
    executor = 'awsbatch'
    queue = 'test-queue'

    errorStrategy = 'retry'
    maxRetries = 3
}

aws {
    batch {
        cliPath = '/home/ec2-user/miniconda/bin/aws'
    }
    region = 'us-east-1'
}
```

Test the pipeline:

```
$ nextflow run nf-core/sarek \
    -ansi-log false \
    -revision 3.1.1 \
    -profile test \
    -work-dir s3://mybucket/work \
    --outdir s3://mybucket/results
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.3
Pulling nf-core/sarek ...
 downloaded from https://github.com/nf-core/sarek.git
Launching `https://github.com/nf-core/sarek` [chaotic_cray] DSL2 - revision: 96749f7421 [3.1.1]


------------------------------------------------------
                                        ,--./,-.
        ___     __   __   __   ___     /,-._.--~'
  |\ | |__  __ /  ` /  \ |__) |__         }  {
  | \| |       \__, \__/ |  \ |___     \`-._,-`-,
                                        `._,._,'
      ____
    .´ _  `.
   /  |\`-_ \      __        __   ___     
  |   | \  `-|    |__`  /\  |__) |__  |__/
   \ |   \  /     .__| /¯¯\ |  \ |___ |  \
    `|____\´

  nf-core/sarek v3.1.1
------------------------------------------------------
Core Nextflow options
  revision                  : 3.1.1
  runName                   : chaotic_cray
  launchDir                 : /home/ec2-user
  workDir                   : /mybucket/work
  projectDir                : /home/ec2-user/.nextflow/assets/nf-core/sarek
  userName                  : ec2-user
  profile                   : test
  configFiles               : /home/ec2-user/.nextflow/config, /home/ec2-user/.nextflow/assets/nf-core/sarek/nextflow.config

Input/output options
  input                     : /home/ec2-user/.nextflow/assets/nf-core/sarek/tests/csv/3.0/fastq_single.csv
  outdir                    : s3://mybucket/results

Main options
  split_fastq               : 0
  intervals                 : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/modules/data/genomics/homo_sapiens/genome/genome.interval_list
  tools                     : strelka

Reference genome options
  genome                    : null
  dbsnp                     : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/modules/data/genomics/homo_sapiens/genome/vcf/dbsnp_146.hg38.vcf.gz
  fasta                     : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/modules/data/genomics/homo_sapiens/genome/genome.fasta
  germline_resource         : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/modules/data/genomics/homo_sapiens/genome/vcf/gnomAD.r2.1.1.vcf.gz
  known_indels              : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/modules/data/genomics/homo_sapiens/genome/vcf/mills_and_1000G.indels.vcf.gz
  snpeff_db                 : WBcel235.105
  snpeff_genome             : WBcel235
  snpeff_version            : 5.1
  vep_genome                : WBcel235
  vep_species               : caenorhabditis_elegans
  vep_cache_version         : 106
  vep_version               : 106.1
  igenomes_base             : s3://ngi-igenomes/igenomes
  igenomes_ignore           : true

Institutional config options
  config_profile_name       : Test profile
  config_profile_description: Minimal test dataset to check pipeline function

Max job request options
  max_cpus                  : 2
  max_memory                : 6.5GB
  max_time                  : 8.h

!! Only displaying parameters that differ from the pipeline defaults !!
------------------------------------------------------
If you use nf-core/sarek for your analysis please cite:

* The pipeline
  https://doi.org/10.12688/f1000research.16665.2
  https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.4468605

* The nf-core framework
  https://doi.org/10.1038/s41587-020-0439-x

* Software dependencies
  https://github.com/nf-core/sarek/blob/master/CITATIONS.md
------------------------------------------------------
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: .*:FREEC_SOMATIC -- Did you mean: FREEC_SOMATIC?
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: .*:FILTERVARIANTTRANCHES -- Did you mean: FILTERVARIANTTRANCHES?
WARN: There's no process matching config selector: NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:CRAM_QC_NO_MD:SAMTOOLS_STATS -- Did you mean: NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:CRAM_QC_RECAL:SAMTOOLS_STATS?
[0a/34e54c] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_INTERVALS:GATK4_INTERVALLISTTOBED (genome)
[68/90b2eb] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_GENOME:TABIX_DBSNP (dbsnp_146.hg38.vcf)
[58/00228d] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_GENOME:SAMTOOLS_FAIDX (genome.fasta)
[87/c64131] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_GENOME:GATK4_CREATESEQUENCEDICTIONARY (genome.fasta)
[91/5140a7] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_GENOME:BWAMEM1_INDEX (genome.fasta)
[a2/823190] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_INTERVALS:CREATE_INTERVALS_BED (genome.interval_list)
[c2/b42dd9] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_GENOME:TABIX_KNOWN_INDELS (mills_and_1000G.indels.vcf)
Staging foreign file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/modules/data/genomics/homo_sapiens/illumina/fastq/test_1.fastq.gz
[87/cb0449] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:FASTQC (test-test_L1)
[f4/86267b] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:PREPARE_INTERVALS:TABIX_BGZIPTABIX_INTERVAL_SPLIT (chr22_1-40001)
[eb/dea090] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:FASTQ_ALIGN_BWAMEM_MEM2_DRAGMAP:BWAMEM1_MEM (test)
[4c/f5096d] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_MARKDUPLICATES:GATK4_MARKDUPLICATES (test)
[b4/ebcc15] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_MARKDUPLICATES:INDEX_MARKDUPLICATES (test)
[c0/8de864] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_MARKDUPLICATES:CRAM_QC_MOSDEPTH_SAMTOOLS:SAMTOOLS_STATS (test)
[be/d73b9d] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_MARKDUPLICATES:CRAM_QC_MOSDEPTH_SAMTOOLS:MOSDEPTH (test)
[68/acdf3e] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_BASERECALIBRATOR:GATK4_BASERECALIBRATOR (test)
[79/cff52c] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_APPLYBQSR:GATK4_APPLYBQSR (test)
[5b/cde6db] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_APPLYBQSR:CRAM_MERGE_INDEX_SAMTOOLS:INDEX_CRAM (test)
[20/d44d7e] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:CRAM_QC_RECAL:SAMTOOLS_STATS (test)
[99/f6362e] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:CRAM_QC_RECAL:MOSDEPTH (test)
[0f/892e88] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:BAM_VARIANT_CALLING_GERMLINE_ALL:BAM_VARIANT_CALLING_SINGLE_STRELKA:STRELKA_SINGLE (test)
[69/ca112a] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:VCF_QC_BCFTOOLS_VCFTOOLS:BCFTOOLS_STATS (test)
[82/2d90d6] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:VCF_QC_BCFTOOLS_VCFTOOLS:VCFTOOLS_TSTV_COUNT (test)
[cd/5be221] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:VCF_QC_BCFTOOLS_VCFTOOLS:VCFTOOLS_TSTV_QUAL (test)
[b8/142b75] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:VCF_QC_BCFTOOLS_VCFTOOLS:VCFTOOLS_SUMMARY (test)
[25/397520] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:CUSTOM_DUMPSOFTWAREVERSIONS (1)
[f6/a9cc92] Submitted process > NFCORE_SAREK:SAREK:MULTIQC
Waiting for file transfers to complete (1 files)
-[nf-core/sarek] Pipeline completed successfully-
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps. I followed this and again I am getting error "caused by: Essential container in task exited
Command executed:
  mkdir bwa
  bwa \
      index \
       \
      -p bwa/genome \
      genome.fasta

Command exit status:
Command output:
  (empty)
Command error:
  bash: /home/ec2-user/miniconda/bin/aws: No such file or directory
  bash: line 1: /home/ec2-user/miniconda/bin/aws: No such file or directory"

Could you please share the  AMI id which you have used?

Comment: No worries at all, @rajangirija. My AMI is private but there's really nothing special about  it though. I basically just followed the instructions to [create your custom AMI](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/aws.html#create-your-custom-ami). You can get the current Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI IDs by region from this [table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) if searching Marketplace proves difficult. Can you confirm that the `aws` tool was installed into the path specified? This is usually `/home/ec2-user/miniconda/bin/aws`.

Comment: Note that you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74596201/edit) your question to include additional details.

Comment: Thank you @Steve Now that I've been able to run the test, however, I encountered the following issue while using my input file.
"Caused by:
  Essential container in task exited
 

Command error:
download failed: s3://ngi-igenomes/igenomes/Homo_sapiens/GATK/GRCh38/Sequence/WholeGenomeFasta/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta to ./Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta [Errno 28] No space left on device"

Comment: @rajangirija Before you create your AMI, make sure to grow your instance's EBS volume to a size large enough to handle your largest job. For Sarek, 300-500 GB is probably enough, but you might need 1 TB or more depending on sequencing depth etc.

Comment: Thank you @steve I have increased the EBS volume to 1TB and now I am getting the below error 
"Caused by:
  Essential container in task exited - CannotInspectContainerError: Could not transition to inspecting; timed out after waiting 30s
Command error:
  main: line 266:    57 Killed                  /home/ec2-user/miniconda/bin/aws --region us-east-2 s3 cp --only-show-errors "$source" "$target"
  download failed: s3://ngs/samples/S2_R1_001.fastq.gz to ./S2_R1_001.fastq.gz [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: @rajangirija `Cannot allocate memory` is usually an OOM error. Try using larger EC2 instances in your compute environment and see how it goes. Were you able to run the pipeline using `-profile test` like in my answer above?

Comment: Yes, I was able to successfully run the pipeline using the -profile test. I have chosen the optimal option available in the EC2 instances in the computing environment.

Comment: @rajangirija Optimal should be fine I think. My guess is that if many jobs are landing on the same instance, you _could_ see memory issues like this. You could try adding `aws.batch.maxParallelTransfers = 1` to your [Batch config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#config-aws-batch) to see if it helps. It might also be worth adding `aws.batch.maxTransferAttempts = 3` for example. Not sure how you're running Sarek, but does just running one sample through work? If you can, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74596201/edit) your question to include the  details, thanks!